# OwlCarousel 2: переключение слайдов по нажатию на кнопки влево/вправо на клавиатуре

Tags: javascript, jquery, вёрстка, owl-carousel

Возможно ли кастомизировать OwlCarousel 2 таким образом, чтобы переключение слайдов происходило не только с помощью кликов по стандартным эл-там управления, а и по нажатию на кнопки "влево/вправо" на клавиатуре? Песочница [здесь](https://codepen.io/Vlastelin/pen/GmjMwW?editors=1010).

```js
$('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
    loop:true,
    margin:10,
    nav:true,
    dots: false,
    items: 2
})
```

```css
.item {
  background: #f0f0f0;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://theappsdepot.com/css/carousel.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/assets/owlcarousel/assets/owl.theme.default.min.css">

    <div id="first-slider" class="tab-pane fade in active">
      <div class="slider owl-carousel owl-theme">
        <div class="item"><h4>1</h4></div>
        <div class="item"><h4>2</h4></div>
        <div class="item"><h4>3</h4></div>
        <div class="item"><h4>4</h4></div>
        <div class="item"><h4>5</h4></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://theappsdepot.com/js/carousel.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это возможно. Надо изменить JS следующим образом:

```
var a = $('.owl-carousel');

a.owlCarousel({ loop:true,
    margin:10,
    nav:true,
    dots: false,
    items: 2});

var ad = a.data('owlCarousel');

$(document).on('keydown.carousel', function(e) {
    if(e.keyCode == 37) {
        ad.prev();
    };
    if(e.keyCode == 39) {
        ad.next();
    };
});
```

Подробнее: https://github.com/OwlFonk/OwlCarousel/issues/65

Пример тут: https://codepen.io/eldinor/pen/JNRMdr?editors=1010